# unable to install laravel-elixir due to node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass, laravel-elixir

Here the log error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\radho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\radho\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\laravel-elixir\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\radho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\radho\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-06T10_58_42_883Z-debug-0.log
```

I think the issue with node-sass

here my config

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmvc2> node -v
v17.8.0
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmvc2> npm -v
8.6.0
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmvc2> gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmvc2>
```

Im using Windows11

I tried to clear the cache, uninstall and re install node-sass, and I used -force flag
still same error

Comment: Same error, did you find any solution?

Comment: had the same problem as you, here is how could solve it : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091641/can-not-install-laravel-elixir)