# Can not install laravel-elixir

Tags: php, laravel, npm

I am trying to install **laraval-elixir** using npm, but I still got the same error when I try to do so. I tried to install older versions, I updated **node-gyp** to the latest version and I even installed **node-sass**, but I am still getting the same following error :

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ecommerce\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22563
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ecommerce\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_l
ibrary="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Here are the **dependencies**
[image]

PS: I installed **node-sass** but the problems still occur when I try to install **laravel-elixir**, even though I tried to install older versions.

Comment: Which node version you are using? It could be that you habe to downgrading to an stable version noder version. for example 14.x etc.

Comment: I am using version 16.13.0 and the LTS is 16.15.0

Comment: Have you perhaps tried a lower version?

Comment: Yes, such kind of error we have faced due to node version only. Even minor version change can also lead this issue. If you are using window, you can try with NVM to try different versions like 14.0.0, 14.12.0,14.17.3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed **NVM** and used it to install both the **LTS** and version **14.12.0**, which I am now using for the project. This version stopped the occurring issue and was able to install laravel-elixir. Thanks to the folks who helped me in the comments. This is the Github page of [NVM](https://https:/https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)